# Blocking three pointers in basketball

Tags: basketball

In basketball, why don't players block three pointers by putting their hand above the hoop and pushing it away? Many players are close to 7 feet and can easily reach the hoop, so why doesn't a player just stand near the hoop and push away three pointers?

Answer (score 13):

This is called goaltending and is prohibited.

In basketball, if you block a shot after it's started descending, it is ruled to be goaltending and the **basket is counted automatically**. There are [several other circumstance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goaltending_(basketball))s in which goal tending is called as well, but they are out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 3):

To provide official rulesets, here are [NBA's - RULE NO. 11](https://official.nba.com/rule-no-11-basket-interference-goaltending/), [FIBA's - Rule 31.2](https://www.fiba.basketball/documents/official-basketball-rules/current.pdf), [NCAA's - Section 15](https://www.ncaapublications.com/productdownloads/BK23.pdf), and [NFHS's - ruleset is paywalled but highlights differences with NCAA's ruleset](https://www.nfhs.org/media/7212540/mbb_wbb_nfhs_major_rules_differences_2023-24_nfhs-edits.pdf) stance on the matter. Each ruleset (in slight variation) states that goaltending occurs after the shot attempt starts downward while it has a chance to be made.